How to achieve statistical queries similar to ArcGIS map services based on CQL queries of GeoServer's WMS service?
In ArcGIS MapServer, through the layer's query interface, it is possible to achieve statistics such as the maximum, minimum, or average of a layer based on a specific category field and a statistic field. For example:
{server site address}/C6100002017111110145309_VectorProduct/MapServer/0/query?where=(1=1) AND (ksbm='C6100002017111110145309') AND (dcpc='2023年7月18日至2023年8月29日')&groupByFieldsForStatistics=yjlmc&outStatistics=[{"statisticType":"sum","onStatisticField":"tbmj","outStatisticFieldName":"funId"}]&f=pjson
Here, where represents the WHERE clause in SQL used to define the scope of the data for statistics; groupByFieldsForStatistics is used to specify the classification field for the statistical results; outStatistics is a parameter for specifying the statistical method (e.g., yjlmc), the field to be statistically analyzed (tbmj), and the name of the output statistical field (funId). After making a GET request to this interface, the corresponding statistical results are returned.result is below:
yjlmc: 草地
sym: 2.7754578948E7

yjlmc: 工矿用地
sym: 2214546.842

yjlmc: 耕地
sym: 1.2288605132E7

yjlmc: 水域及水利设施用地
sym: 370459.813

yjlmc: 住宅用地
sym: 2852652.575

yjlmc: 其他土地
sym: 2169715.099

yjlmc: 特殊用地
sym: 138935.889

yjlmc: 公共管理与公共服务用地
sym: 19046.213

yjlmc: 林地
sym: 5.8148470369E7

yjlmc: 交通运输用地
sym: 2496411.692

yjlmc: 商业服务业用地
sym: 108624.266

This method achieves the total area statistics for each yjlmc.
I'm wondering if there's a similar interface in GeoServer's WMS to achieve the same functionality. I've already tried using CQL for statistical queries on the data, but currently, CQL only supports the WHERE clause.

No, the functionality you are looking for is provided via the OGC WPS specification. You might be able to chain together existing functions on your server or you may need to write some code to do it.
